# how to get all attached printers name on our computer using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

my scenario is...
I'm making a web application for a restaurant using (**NodeJS** and **Angular 12**), and they are using thermal printers, all printers connected via USB and LAN.
I need a solution - how I can get the list of all connected printers and print receipts on all printers without a preview dialog box..!!!

currently, I'm not able to list all connected printers list,
and print receipts on them

please help me to find a proper solution

Comment: Are these printers  Epson or Star thermal printers?

Comment: Yes, I'm using both printers along with normal printers as well

Comment: You might find this useful, -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer   Not sure it has a way to list printers, but if you supply the IP address / printername etc and type of printer and have this stored somewhere.  It should allow you to print automatically to these printers.

Answer (score 0):

There was a `node-printer`module but I guess it was abandoned, the last most recent module for that is [zuzel-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zuzel-printer), but the last update is from 6 years ago. Let's hope it fits your needs

Link: **zuzel-printer** https://www.npmjs.com/package/zuzel-printer

Answer (score 0):

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('wmic printer list brief', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
}
// list of printers with brief details
console.log(stdout);
// the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
stdout = stdout.split("  ");
var printers = [];
j = 0;
stdout = stdout.filter(item => item);
for (i = 0; i < stdout.length; i++) {
    if (stdout[i] == " \r\r\n" || stdout[i] == "\r\r\n") {
        printers[j] = stdout[i + 1];
        j++;
    }
}
// list of only printers name
console.log(printers);
console.log(stderr);
});
```

Comment: wmic is Windows only and ->`The WMI command-line (WMIC) utility is deprecated as of Windows 10, version 21H1,`